# C# GeckoFX - How to use SendKeyEvent with Vietnamese string

Tags: c#, geckofx

I used GeckoFX instead of .NET webControl component to make automative tool, in GeckoFX supported method was called: SendKeyEvent().
I wanna send string to browser with vietnamese message by this method but output is encrypted string:

Sample string:

> đây là tiếng việt

And here my code

```
byte[] tmp_cmt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(comment);
char[] tmp_rsl = comment.ToCharArray();
txtLog.AppendText("Starting COMMENT....\n");
webBrowser1.Window.DomWindow.Focus();
int a = 0;
while (a < comment.Length)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    bool sd = webBrowser1.Window.WindowUtils.SendKeyEvent("keypress", 0, tmp_cmt[a], 0, true);
    if (!sd) { Utilityx.Log(tmp_cmt[a].ToString() + " - "); a++; }
    Application.DoEvents();
}
txtLog.AppendText("Pressing `Enter` key to submit comment...\n");
webBrowser1.Window.WindowUtils.SendKeyEvent("keydown", 13, 0, 0, true);
webBrowser1.Window.WindowUtils.SendKeyEvent("keyup", 13, 0, 0, true);
```

And here result:

> ?ay l? ti?ng vi?t

How to made it work ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your result there is what you would see if the font being used doesn't have the symbols for the corresponding unicode characters. That is, could it be that your code *is* working, but you are viewing the result in the wrong font?

Comment: @John Hatton: I tried type manually and its font shown as well, I think that this problem come from encoding, but now i don't have any solution for this

Comment: OK. So do you really need to use SendKey? Could you maybe instead insert the utf8 encoded string you want direction into the DOM? You could do this either by adding your own javascript to the client side and invoking it from c#, or by digging into the DOM directly from c#.

Comment: Thanks JH, i've been solved problem by SZ's solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature for the method is

```
SendKeyEvent(string aType, int aKeyCode, int aCharCode, int aModifiers, bool aPreventDefault)
```

I don't know if `keyCode`, for which you sent 0 is important, but certainly `charCode` is **not** a `byte` in the UTF8 encoding of the string. Instead, you should try to use `(int)comment[a]`

The problem I see here is that probably for Vietnamese characters multiple keys need to be pressed. If `SendKeyEvent` doesn't know how to translate it itself, then probably you need to do some complicated key emulations.

Comment: Thanks @Siderite Zackwehdex: Problem solved completely.